# Evaluate the following: $ \int _0^3 \frac{x^2dx}{\sqrt{9-x^2}}$

Tags: integration

Evaluate the following:

$$ \int _0^3 \frac{x^2dx}{\sqrt{9-x^2}}$$

I substituted: $$x=3\sin{\theta}$$

And got: $$ 3\int _0^3 \frac{\sin^2\theta}{\cos\theta}d\theta$$

Q1: Am I right so far?

Q2: Where do I go from here?

I've considered: [$\frac{\sin\theta}{\cos\theta}=\tan\theta$], [$\sin^2\theta=\frac{1}{2}(1-\cos2\theta)$]  and [$\sin^2\theta=1-\cos^2\theta$].

Where does one go from here?

Answer should be $\frac{9\pi}{4}$

Also I notice that x cannot be equal to 3. ie: x=3 is a vertical asymptote to this function. Does this imply that the area from 0 to 3 approaches infinity?

Comment: There are two big mistakes in your substitution. The first: you forgot $\mathrm{d} x = 3 \cos \theta \mathrm{d} \theta$. Second: you should consider $\theta \in [0, \pi /2]$, not $\theta \in [0,3]$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

doing your substitution you should have $$9\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\sin^2\theta \,d\theta$$ (you forgot that $dx=\cos\theta d\theta$)

Now use $\sin^2\theta=\frac 12(1-\cos2\theta)$

Comment: You are right David , I forgot to substitute for dx. Thanks.

Comment: you're welcome.

Answer (score 2):

$$ \int _0^3 \frac{x^2dx}{\sqrt{9-x^2}}=9\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\sin^2\theta \,d\theta$$
apply $\sin^2\theta=\frac{1-\cos 2 \theta}{2} $

Answer (score 1):

Q1: It's not right.
By the substitution $x = 3sin(x)$ the resulting integral is $9\int sin^2(x)$ and the resulting interval of integration is $[0, pi/2]$.

Q2: $\int sin^2(x) $ can be solved for example by the identity $sin^2(x) = {1 - cos(2x)\over 2}$.

Answer (score 0):

$$\\ 9\int _{ 0 }^{ \frac { \pi  }{ 2 }  } \sin ^{ 2 }{ \theta  } d\theta =9\int _{ 0 }^{ \frac { \pi  }{ 2 }  }{ \frac { 1-\cos { 2\theta  }  }{ 2 }  } d\theta =\frac { 9 }{ 2 } \int _{ 0 }^{ \frac { \pi  }{ 2 }  }{ \left( 1-\cos { 2\theta  }  \right) d\theta  } =\frac { 9 }{ 2 } { \left( \theta -\frac { \sin { 2\theta  }  }{ 2 }  \right)  }_{ 0 }^{ \frac { \pi  }{ 2 }  }=\\ =\frac { 9\pi  }{ 4 }  $$

Comment: Having carefully noted $dx$ you failed to use it!

Comment: But the $\cos\theta$ cancels.

Comment: @almagest,thanks i've fixed it

Comment: Ok, that is now correct.